# React Native: Why can't you get hot reloading on two devices at once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, bundler, metro-bundler

I ran my React Native app on a real device, then plugged in a second device, opened a new command prompt, and ran the app on the second device. I can use the app on both devices at once, but if I edit the code, live reloading occurs on only the second device.
Can anyone explain why this happens? Is it something to do with the bundler being able to serve only one device at a time?

Comment: i can using RN0.6x. but in my case i used iOS and android devices at once, not same OS, and i use xcode to run for iOS and cmd for android

Comment: Multi-client HMR support should not be a problem https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/8b2975ad7b27ce34dcf56836685fd54ddd62086c more on https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6179 and https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/7475. Please check if your bundle is configured correctly for multi-client HMR.